# Function reinitialise() will be executed before its call

Tags: jquery

Before the proper call of function `reinitialise()` (by the function `reinitializeScrollbar()`) the function will be executed.
Has anyone an idea why?

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.scrollContainer').jScrollPane();

    $('[id^=arr]').click(function (event) {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var index = id.substring(4);
        //alert('Gib ID aus: ' +index);
        var skillDesc = "#skillDescript" + index;

        var arrTo2 = "#arr_" + index + ".arrow2";
        var arrTo1 = "#arr_" + index + ".arrow1";

        //alert('Gib skillDesc aus: ' +skillDesc);
        event.preventDefault();
        if ($(skillDesc).css("display") != "none") {
            $(skillDesc).slideUp(800, reinitializeScrollbar());
            console.log("ROLL IN!");
            $(arrTo2).toggleClass("arrow2", "arrow1");
        } else {
            $(skillDesc).slideDown(800, reinitializeScrollbar());
            console.log("ROLL OUT!");
            $(arrTo1).toggleClass("arrow2");
        }
    });

    function reinitializeScrollbar() {
        $('.scrollContainer').data('jsp').reinitialise();
        console.log("damn you");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are *calling* the function when you try to set up the event handler:

```
$(skillDesc).slideUp(800, reinitializeScrollbar());
```

Instead, you just should pass the function itself as a parameter:

```
$(skillDesc).slideUp(800, reinitializeScrollbar);
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing currently is calling the function immediately, by adding `()`.  What this will do is call the function immediately and then take the result of that function call, and pass that value as the callback.  Since you want to pass the function itself, you should not call the function, simply pass it as the callback:

```
$(skillDesc).slideUp(800, reinitializeScrollbar);
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct syntax is:

```
$(skillDesc).slideUp(800, reinitializeScrollbar);
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$(skillDesc).slideUp(800, reinitializeScrollbar);
```

or

```
$(skillDesc).slideUp(800, function(){ reinitializeScrollbar() });
```

Comment: It does not make a difference in this example, but probably it should be mentioned there is a difference in how the `reinitializeScrollbar` is called. In the first one the _context_ (`this`) of `reinitializeScrollbar` is the element that is `slidedUp`, for the second one it is the `window` object.

Answer (score 0):

This would most probably be because you're actually calling the `reinitializeScrollbar()` function where you instead want to assign it as a callback.

This should solve it:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.scrollContainer').jScrollPane();

    $('[id^=arr]').click(function (event) {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var index = id.substring(4);
        //alert('Gib ID aus: ' +index);
        var skillDesc = "#skillDescript" + index;

        var arrTo2 = "#arr_" + index + ".arrow2";
        var arrTo1 = "#arr_" + index + ".arrow1";

        //alert('Gib skillDesc aus: ' +skillDesc);
        event.preventDefault();
        if ($(skillDesc).css("display") != "none") {
            $(skillDesc).slideUp(800, reinitializeScrollbar);
            console.log("ROLL IN!");
            $(arrTo2).toggleClass("arrow2", "arrow1");
        } else {
            $(skillDesc).slideDown(800, reinitializeScrollbar);
            console.log("ROLL OUT!");
            $(arrTo1).toggleClass("arrow2");
        }
    });

    function reinitializeScrollbar() {
        $('.scrollContainer').data('jsp').reinitialise();
        console.log("damn you");
    }
});
```